# PyTorch: Custom Sampler for sampling classes with changing probabilities?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to implement a custom sampler in PyTorch. I have a classification problem and I want to sample data in each batch by sampling classes non-uniformly, with probabilities that change batch-to-batch, and then sampling data uniformly within each class.

So for instance, if I'm using CIFAR10 with a batch size 32 and initial probabilities `[0.5, 0.5, 0, ..., 0]`, I want to sample only the first 2 classes with equal probability e.g. `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1...0]`, and then sample 32 points uniformly from within each sampled class. After the first batch, I may want the probabilities to shift to `[0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0, ..., 0]`, meaning I want to sample from the first three classes with those probabilities.

How can I implement this in a custom pytorch `Sampler`?